# How can I cache an output of 404 response in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core

In our app (ASP.NET Core 3.1), we are having a lot of 404 requests. On each request, the app queries the database and performs some calculations. The output for the same URL rarely changes.
To improve the performance, I would like to setup output caching for this service so that the same requests will return cached output even for 404.

According to the documentation, only responses with 200 status code are cached:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Is there a way to override this behavior and set "cachable" status codes? Or is there another way to achieve this?